# Is every 3-Sasakian a Sasakian-Einstein manifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sasakian-geometry

a short question: Is every 3-Sasakian manifold a Sasaki-Einstein manifold? If not, do you have an example? If yes, how can I prove this?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because a manifold is Sasaki-Einstein if and only if its metric cone is Ricci-flat Kähler, whereas the cone of a 3-sasakian manifold is hyperkähler.

See, for instance, Bär's "[Real Killing spinors and holonomy](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02102106)" published in CMP.

Comment: Okay, I thought this... If someone is hyperkähler, is this Ricci-flat Kähler, too? What I mean: What is the connection between hyperkähler and Ricci-flat Kähler?

Thanks!

Comment: A hyperkähler manifold is Ricci-flat Kähler in a variety of ways -- that variety being $\mathbb{CP}^1$.